# is there a XNOR operator in javascript

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators

I'm new to js and I wonder if there is a XNOR operator in JS.  I tried !`(a^b)` but it gives weird result.  For example:

```
var a,b="aa"; 
a^b
```

this code returns true, however, I XNOR returns false.

**UPDATE**
I need to return true if the two operand are **true**(different from false values), or the two are **false** (both equals to : null, undefined,""-empty string- or 0)

Comment: Isn't it just the equivalent of `==`?

Comment: Have you considered using xor and not in chain? Also what is this `var a,b="aa"; a^b`? It looks completely wrong and doesn't give true at all.

Comment: [Same question in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054124/is-there-xnor-logical-biconditional-operator-in-c) - hesitant to close as a dupe (hence why I undid my dupehammer vote) due to it being a different language.

Comment: Why are you trying to compare a string and an undefined value with bitwise operators?!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[image: XNOR truth table]

Above is the truth table for XNOR.  If A and B are both FALSE or TRUE, the resulting XNOR is true.  Therefore, it seems to me as if simply checking for equality is actually the equivalent of XNOR.

So:

```
(a === b) = (a XNOR b)
```

EDIT: to work properly with your conditions: this should work:

```
a == b
```

Note that there are two "=", not three, indicating that this is comparing "truthy" values.

Comment: @aName Then use `!a === !b` if you need to cast your values to proper booleans first

Comment: I've updated my answer, try this: a == b (note that there are only two equal signs, not three).

Comment: that's it @Bergi

Answer (score 18):

The bitwise xnor is:

```
~(a ^ b)
```

And the logical one;

```
a === b
```

Answer (score 0):

try `(a^b)==0`
 i think result of XNOR in javascript is: `true^true = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it this simple?

!(A ^ B)

The inverse of XOR.

Answer (score -1):

try this `(!(A ^ B))`
or this `(A && B) || (!A && !B)`

Comment: Bitwise not is `~`

Comment: yeah that what I'm using now, but I wonder if there is an operator that makes it simpler